# Google Chrome unloads discrete GPU memory - causes initial lag (around 1-2 seconds) when start scrolling

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, laptop, gpu, vram

Ever since I switched chrome graphics settings to gtx1060 from Intel HD 630 on my laptop (in nvidia control panel) I had this lag when trying to scroll page after around 30 seconds of idling.

Win10 task manager shows that lag happens after gpu unloads memory (only chrome is running on discrete gpu). When I start scrolling gpu takes a couple of seconds to start using vram (around 0.1~0.2GB) and only then unfreezes.

Disabling everything in chrome://flags didn't help.

Turning on high-performance in windows settings didn't help either.

Running on integrated graphics helps, but it's a worse option (for a laptop that always works on AC plug).

NVidia driver: 445.87

Here's my chrome://gpu features:

`Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
OpenGL: Enabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Unavailable
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated`

Comment: Since Chrome scroll is threaded, instead of vectorial, you're bound to have rendering/painting issues of the sort, especially on big monitors and/or screens with a high definition or many pixels in height, or both. I were you, I'd disable rasterization altogether, just to check if it helps. You can even add the flag at the end of your executable ("--no-gpu-rasterization"). See here for more details: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/how-to-get-gpu-rasterization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by switching 'Power management mode' to 'Prefer maximum performance' in NVIDIA Control Panel.